# HTML to readable text in Swift

Tags: html, css, xcode, swift, human-readable

I need to make a reader func in my Swift App. I will receive text (with json request) in HTML like this :

```
<h5 align="LEFT" class="western" style="font-weight: normal;"> </h5>
<font size="3"><h5 align="LEFT" class="western" style="font-weight: normal;">
Albert Einstein publie en 1905, une nouvelle théorie connue sous le nom de relativité restreinte. </h5>
<h5 align="LEFT" class="western" style="font-weight: normal;"></h5>
<h5 align="LEFT" style="font-weight: normal;"><font color="#339933">►</font>
<font size="3">Postulat 1&nbsp;:</font>
</h5><h5 align="LEFT" class="western" style="font-weight: normal;">
</h5>
```

And I want to show it in readable text with all the attribute, I don't want to lose the style, for that I can use HTMLReader.

Do you know a way to make it in Swift ?

Comment: Try embedding that into valid html and then display it with a UIWebView/NSWebView

Comment: You wan't the text and the attribute? Or just the text?

Comment: The text like on a web view, I think JoJoe reply to my question except if it exist something better.

Answer (score 0):

These are define in html file, then have to use webview:

```
objweb.delegate = self
        var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath

        var baseUrl  = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("\(path)")

        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        let pathhtml = bundle.pathForResource("Armory", ofType: "html")
        let content = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(pathhtml) as String

        objweb.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: baseUrl)
        self.view.addSubview(objweb)
```